# How to get auto sum required in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

Hi all I filter count and quality, I need to total sum value can be changed to corresponding filtered data equally auto sum generate  using getTotals() functionality in meanjs app. then i tried many ways but unable to get the solution if any one knows the solution please help me... http://plnkr.co/edit/IBPd8Dx6hmfWHULKrIBi?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<td><p>{{getTotals()}}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{getTotalss()}}</p></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example of using a function to dynamically generate a value bound to the HTML template.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', MyController);

function MyController() {
  this.myArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
}

MyController.prototype.getTotal = function() {
  var total = 0;
  for (e of this.myArray) {
    total += e;
  }
  return total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController as vm">
    Total: {{vm.getTotal()}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need filter count and quality , total sum value changed to corresponding filtered data equally auto sum generate it's like dynamically not define value in controller.Please see example code link http://plnkr.co/edit/IBPd8Dx6hmfWHULKrIBi?p=preview and help me...